# Splitting a string by capital letters

Tags: python

I currently have the following code, which finds capital letters in a string 'formula': http://pastebin.com/syRQnqCP

Now, my question is, how can I alter that code (Disregard the bit within the "if choice = 1:" loop) so that each part of that newly broken up string is put into it's own variable?

For example, putting in NaBr would result in the string being broken into "Na" and "Br". I need to put those in separate variables so I can look them up in my CSV file. 
Preferably it'd be a kind of generated thing, so if there are 3 elements, like MgSO4, O would be put into a separate variable like Mg and S would be.

If this is unclear, let me know and I'll try and make it a bit more comprehensible... No way of doing so comes to mind currently, though. :(

EDIT: Relevant pieces of code:

Function:

```
def split_uppercase(string):
x=''
for i in string: 
    if i.isupper(): x+=' %s' %i 
    else: x+=i 
return x.strip()
```

String entry and lookup:

```
formula = raw_input("Enter formula: ")
upper = split_uppercase(formula)

#Pull in data from form.csv
weight1 = float(formul_data.get(element1.lower()))
weight2 = float(formul_data.get(element2.lower()))
weight3 = float(formul_data.get(element3.lower()))


weightSum = weight1 + weight2 + weight3
print "Total weight =", weightSum
```

Comment: Would you please post the *relevant* parts of your code here?

Comment: Sorry, thought it would be better to have the full code so that there was less confusion as to the different things used. Relevant parts now up in the post.

Comment: Thanks .. it just makes it easier (and you can be sure, people *will* ask for more code if they feel they need it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think there is a far easier way to do what you're trying to do.  Use regular expressions.  For instance:

```
>>> [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]
['Mg', u'S', u'O', u'4']
```

If you want the number attached to the right element, just add a digit specifier in the regex:

```
>>> [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*\d*)', txt) if a]
[u'Mg', u'S', u'O4']
```

You don't really want to "put each part in its own variable".  That doesn't make sense in general, because you don't know how many parts there are, so you can't know how many variables to create ahead of time.  Instead, you want to make a list, like in the example above.  Then you can iterate over this list and do what you need to do with each piece.

Comment: +1 for using `re.split()` (I was just going to suggest that) and for the advice of using a list to store the results instead of dealing with a unknown number of variables

Comment: The only reason I wanted them in different variables was for the lookup, because I'm eventually going to be finding weights and adding them together, much like in the part under "if choice = 1:" in the full code on pastebin. I'll look into what you've described, though, cheers. Quick note, this is going to come from a raw_input, so I'm not sure how to replace MgSO4 in your code with what comes from the entry in the raw_input.

Comment: @dantdj: but look at your weight addition code.  You have three lines which differ only in the names.  If you use a list, you could simply write `weight_sum = sum(float(formul_data.get(elem.lower())) for elem in elements)`, etc, and then you could handle any number of elements.  [With a tweak to handle the numbers, of course.]

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, cheers. The 3 lines are basically just there for testing, I would have tried cutting those out later. I tend to focus on getting one bit of code down at at a time. The weight addition code can be done after I've got this entry code fully working. :p

Comment: On a serious note, though, I seriously can't figure out how I'm meant to use this in order to get the functionality I'm needing. :( I've tried, but I can't seem to get it done.

Comment: @dantdj: Well, I've showed you how to split the string on capital letters, which was your question here.  If you have a question about how to use that data, you might want to ask a separate question saying specifically what you're trying to do.

Comment: I figured the whole thing was a bit too much to put in a title (Heh, yes, that excuse again), so I kind of expanded on it in the body of the post. I'll go ahead and do that, though. Cheers for the help, it's appreciated! :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use re.split to perform complex splitting on strings.

```
import re

def split_upper(s):
    return filter(None, re.split("([A-Z][^A-Z]*)", s))

>>> split_upper("fooBarBaz")
['foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']
>>> split_upper("fooBarBazBB")
['foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'B', 'B']
>>> split_upper("fooBarBazBB4")
['foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'B', 'B4']
```