# Using a list to divide and store a string to be used in a variable

Tags: python, list

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124275/splitting-a-string-by-capital-letters-python), it was suggested that, in order to divide a string and store it, I should use a list, like so:

```
[a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]
['Mg', u'S', u'O', u'4']
```

What I'd like to ask this time around is how would I be able to use that to store the different strings created into variables so I can look them up in the CSV file I have, if it's at all possible. Where it says 'MgSO4' would be coming from a variable called 'formula', which is produced from a raw_input, like so:

```
formula = raw_input("Enter formula: ")
```

Full program code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/3G761hb0), and I've included the more relevant part below. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
formula = raw_input("Enter formula: ")


[a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]

weight_sum = sum(float(formul_data.get(elem.lower())) for elem in elements)
print "Total weight =", weightSum
```

Comment: What do you want to do once you look them up in the CSV file?  From your example it looks as if you already are looking them up (with `formul_data.get(elem.lower())`).  Also, I assume you want an `elements = ` on the front of that line with the `re.split` list comprehension?

Comment: I want to find the weights of the elements given, and then add them together. The code at the top of my program pulls in data from the two CSV files I have in order to do this. And yeah, I suppose I would want `elements =  ` on there. My preferred solution would have been some way of taking the elements and putting them into variables and then looking THOSE up, but that's mainly because it's the only way I know how. Any other way I'm a bit dodgy on, so it'd need a bit of explanation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not readng the code in your pastebin correctly, but it looks to me like the `weight_sum = ...` line you posted *does* add the weights.  What is it not doing that you need it to do?

Comment: Gah, sorry, even I'm starting to get confused now. I suppose my only problem here is the TypeErrors that seem to come up: http://i.imgur.com/8VjRM.png I put in HCO as the input, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to be able to add up the molecular weights of the atoms comprising a molecule, I suggest doing your regular expressions a bit differently. Instead of having the numbers mixed in with the element symbols in your split list, attach them to the preceding element instead (and attach a 1 if there was no number). Here's how I'd do that:

```
import re

# a partial table of atomic weights, replace with something better!
weights = { "H" : 1,  "Na": 11, "Mg": 12, "C" : 12, "N" : 14,
            "O" : 16, "F" : 19, "Al": 27, "S" : 32, "Cl": 35, 
      }

def molecularWeight(formula):
    matches = re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z]?)([0-9]*)", formula)
    return sum(weights[symbol] * (int(count) if count else 1)
               for (symbol, count) in matches)
```

To make this fit with the code you've shown, replace `weights[symbol]` with something like `formul_data.get(symbol.lower(), 0)` (or whatever is necessary to get appropriate atomic weights by symbol in your code).

This should handle any empiric formula, and many structural ones, as long as there are no parentheses. To solve fully parenthesized formulas you'll need to make a better parser, as simple regular expressions won't work.

Comment: Would it be at all feasible to replace that weights list with data imported from a CSV like I already have? Putting all of that data into the .py file would be incredibly messy.

Comment: @dantdj: Yes, absolutely. I just did that so I could test something out quickly.

Answer (score 1):

After running

```
>>> import re
>>> elements = [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', 'MgSO4') if a]
```

you can access the splitted parts using indices

```
>>> print elements[0]
'Mg'
>>> print elements[-1]  # print the last element
'4'
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot! Is there any way I could account for differences in the length of the formula, however? For example, CH3COOH instead of MgSO4.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but it may be that you're not realizing that the `re.split` code can be applied to any string, including the string you read from `raw_input`.  Is this what you're asking for?

```
formula = raw_input("Enter formula: ")

elements = [a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', formula) if a]

weight_sum = sum(float(formul_data.get(elem.lower(), 0)) for elem in elements)
print "Total weight =", weight_sum
```

Comment: Yeah, I got that done now. Only problem is the TypeErrors (Look at the comments on my question)

Comment: @dantdj: See my edited answer (note the added zero).  The problem is that in parsing the formula you are also getting numbers (like the 4 in MgSO4) and not just element names.

Comment: Using that clears any errors, but then I don't get the weight added properly: http://i.imgur.com/UndWU.png It must be something dodgy in this line `weightSum = sum(float(formul_data.get(elem.lower(), 0)) for elem in elements)`, but I'm not quite sure what it is. Perhaps the use of `elem` instead of `elements`?

Comment: Well, again, you are moving beyond your original question.  You asked how to split up the string into elements.  That's been done, but that doesn't automatically result in O being counted 4 times in "MgSO4".  Currently you are ignoring the 4 in your calculation.  If you want to take account of it you will need to do more than just parse the element names.  You will have to also parse the numbers and multiply the corresponding elements by their counts.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using MgSO4 as my input here, just HCO in this case. No numbers in the formula whatsoever. While, yes, even that could be viewed as going outside the scope of my original question, it's not too far out, and I don't want to clutter up the site more than I have done with multiple posts about a very similar topic, especially seeing as this problem is probably limited to just one line.

Comment: @dantdj: I made another edit.  In your original code, but you read the sum into `weight_sum` but then print `weightSum`.  I didn't notice this error and copied it into my answer.  With that change, and using a fake version of `formul_data` that just has h, c, and o in it, it works for me.  Perhaps the problem is in your reading of the CSV file containing the weights, or in the format of that file itself?

Comment: I made that change before to my code, so no need to worry there. That wasn't the cause of the problem, though. :p Turns out changing elem to elements doesn't work either... damnit.

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: @dantdj: What does the most current version of your code look like?

Comment: @martineau: Hah, sorry, figured out what was wrong. Wasn't in the Python at all, it was something in the CSV. Must learn to check the supporting files as well...